# Simplifying equation using trigonometric sum and differences identities

Tags: trigonometry

Recently started learning trigonometric identities in school, having problems with this one. Tried solving using the sum and differences identities but keep having repeating everything. Thanks.

$\frac{-\cos(x)\sin(x)\pm \cos(y)\sin(y)}{\sin^2(y)-\cos^2(x)}=\tan(x\mp y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$LHS = \frac{-\cos x \sin x + \cos y \sin y}{\sin^2y-\cos^2x} = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\sin(2y)-\sin(2x)}{\sin^2y-\cos^2y} = \dfrac{\sin(y-x)\cos(y+x)}{\sin^2y-\cos^2x} $$

> $\sin(-z) = -\sin(z)$ So $\sin(y-x) = -\sin(x-y)$

$$\begin{align}& LHS = \dfrac{\sin(x-y)\cos(y+x)}{\color{blue}{\cos^2x-\sin^2y}} = \dfrac{\sin(x-y)\cos(x+y)}{\color{blue}{\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)}}\\
& \ = \dfrac{\sin(x-y)}{\cos(x-y)} =\tan(x-y) =RHS\end{align}$$

> Use $y = -y$ to get the other one.

For the blue highlighted part (a short proof)

> $\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[\cos(2x)+\cos(2y)\right] = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[(2\cos^2x -1) + (1-2\sin^2y)\right]\\ = \cos^2x-\sin^2y$

Comment: Is it possible to do all this without picking one of the signs? Because I have already tried deriving both by picking one either the + or -, and it works, but when I tried to directly use the ± to derive the equations it doesn't work.

Comment: It'll work, just remember $\cos(\pm z ) = \cos(z)$ , $\sin(\pm z) = \pm\sin(z)$. So you can rewrite the numerator  as $-\cos(x)\sin(x) + \cos(\pm y)\sin(\pm y)$. And obviously, $\sin^2(\pm z) =  (\pm \sin z)^2 = \sin^2(z)$ . So the denominator can be written as, $\sin^2(\pm y) - \cos^2(x)$ Let $\pm y = u$ and proceed. Finally you'll get $\tan(x-u) = \tan(x-(\pm y)) = \tan(x \mp y)$